# Auto-resizing components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans-7

I am making a forum programmed in Java and I'm starting to work on getting posts and threads right. For GUI I'm using the netbeans guy builder. I plan to put a text area inside a pane, along with the user's avatar and some other info, as a post. If I understand text areas right, they won't autoresize, instead they'll show scroll bars. Can I make them auto resize?

The same thing goes for jpanels, can I make them auto resize as well?

Comment: Why are you doing this? (asking because it sounds extremely silly)

Comment: @MightyPork What part of it are you asking about? Auto-resizing components? Because it looks better.

Comment: No, writing a "forum" in Java. If it was a good & useful idea, it'd be widespread by now.

Comment: @MightyPork I'm going to be doing some text parsing that I'd like to do in Java, because it's my best language, and it's for school.

Comment: Well then, personally I'd use PHP, but if it's for school, so be it. Look into SpringLayout, that might be what you want for the resizing. (a bit hard to work with, but it can get the job done).

Comment: @MightyPork Just realized part of what sounded silly about this. The "forum" I'm writing uses a downloaded app to handle user interface. The online part will be only data, or maybe a java server to make sure things go smoothly. Testing the SpringLayout now.

Comment: @MightyPork So is there anyway to make JTextArea just resize, not display scroll bars.

Comment: There certainly is, I'm doing it in my project. Search layout managers on google, there's a page "Visual Guide To Layout Managers", very useful reference and some example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, but I feel kinda stupid. Both JTextAreas, and JPanels auto-resize on their own, unless they are wrapped in a JScrollPanel. So just watch how you place JScrollPanels.